# CDF and personalized style

Tags: formatting, cdf-format

I recently created a custom stylesheet. I then created a notebook with the new style, confirmed that the notebook had adopted the style, and then saved a copy in CDF. But when I opened the CDF in Wolfram's CDF Player, the style had not been applied to the document. Does this mean that CDFs are not able to adopt the style of the original notebook if the style comes from a custom stylesheet? How can I embed the style into cdf?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered no problems here. My system: *Mathematica* 8.0.4 WIN7. My workflow:

1) **File > New > Notebook**

2) **Format > Edit Stylesheet...** I applied new styles to Title, Subtitle and Section.

3) Enter your content in *Mathematica* notebook.

4) **File > Deploy > Standalone...** This will produce a CDF file with inherited styles.

Here is the snapshot of CDF file I created opened in *Wolfram CDF Player* - as you can see all styles are preserved:

[image]

Comment: There are many problems. If you create your own stylesheet different from the default ones in mathemtica, for example a stylesheet "test" in wich we have defined a particular framed cell, and apply it to notebook, when we deply a standalone cdf, it doesn't open correctly in the player. We have the message box: "the file is basen upon the stylesheet "test" wich cannot be found in mathematica. I'im finding a workaround to include my own styles in the standalone cdf instead.....

Comment: I think that you will need to embed the stylesheet in the notebook, which will be done automatically when you choose Format > Edit Stylesheet as Vitaliy has suggested, then make a change and save the document. If you define a named stylesheet and use that, you would probably have to deliver this along with your cdf, but I'm not sure whether the CDF-Player does actually allow the usage of such stylesheets, at least it misses the menu entries to install them.

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov Is there a difference between the straightforward saving a notebook as CDF via File/Save As and choosing CDF on one hand,  and saving as standalone via File/CDF Export/Standalone (This is in Mma9.01) on the other hand?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I've found several differences.  One is: no cell brackets appear if created with CDF Export.  Another is: cell openers are buggy with CDF Export: if code is included with an interface (`Manipulate` &c) and the cell is opened then the interface disappears, forever it seems... I conclude that CDF Export is buggy and not the best way of creating CDF documents.  This could be related to the specific stylesheet I was using or the version/OS, I've 9.01 on a Mac