# CDF to give away with a custom StyleSheet

Tags: formatting, cdf-format, stylesheet

Related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/cdf-and-personalized-style).

I would like to be able to give away CDF documents created with a custom StyleSheet.

The important peculiarity is that this document is assumed to be viewed on a machine with no such StyleSheet.

The second one is that in the cases I have in mind delivering a separate file with the StyleSheet to be installed on that machine is absolutely out of question.

The StyleSheet should be, therefore, somehow embedded into the document, if this is possible.

This is the difference with respect to the answer I mentioned in the beginning. There Vitaly Kaurov created a custom StyleSheet, using it produced a CDF file and opened it on the same machine.

On the other hand modifications may be subtle. That is, the StyleSheet in question is built by a slight modification of one of the existing StyleSheets, such as increased line spacing, increased font size and, may be, few others.

My question: do you see such a possibility?

Comment: Vitaly's answer in the link your provided gives you embedded private styles.