# Styling differences between CDF in CDF player and in MMA

Tags: stylesheet, cdfplayer

I've used the ConfidentialReport stylesheet for a CDF document.  When I edit the CDF within MMA a Paragraph Item appears with an opener as follows:
[image]

but when the document is opened in the Player itself, the opener is not there.  Does anyone know of a systemic reason why, or a fix?  (I've a related question about local stylesheets for CDF documents but there's quite a bit of discussion already which I need to trawl through first...)

Comment: In Mathematica 9.0.1, ItemParagraph has no opener for me on Windows, using ConfidentialReport stylesheet. Please state your operating system and the Mathematica and CDF versions you are using.

Comment: 9.0.1 MMA and CDF player.  In fact I was surprised to see the opener was there, but it was exactly what I wanted; so I was surprised to see the different behaviour in exactly the same CDF document in the 2 environments.  I did apply the stylesheet after creating the CDF from within a notebook that did not have the same stylesheet, if that makes a difference.

Comment: MacOS Mavericks btw

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things one can do in this case. If your CDF notebook is not too large you might do the following:

I take it that your initial notebook has the `GroupOpeners`, or may be not. Independently of this:

1. Open the notebook which you are going to transform into CDF in *Mathematica*.
2. Place the cursor into the cell that you want to have a `GroupOpener`.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. The cell will transform into a text. Type in `ShowGroupOpener->True` within the square parenthesis, as it is shown in the picture below:
   [image]
4. Now place the cursor into this cell again and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Done
5. Repeat this with all cells you want to have the group openers in the CDF format.
6. Now transform this document into the CDF: `Menu/File/CDF Export/Standalone` 
   The cells of your choice of the resulting CDF document will have the `GroupOpeners`. At least I get them in *Mathematica 9.0.1.0*. Have a look below
   [image]
   The left document is the source notebook (I did not save it, and, therefore, it has no name). The right one is the resulting CDF notebook entitled `"Example.cdf"`. For the sake of example I only added the `GroupOpeners` to the `Section 1` and `Subsection 1`, while `Section 2` and `Subsection 2` are left as they initially were.

There is another way also. It is to add the `GroupOpener` to the `StyleSheet` of the notebook to the definitions of certain cells of your choice. It can be done such that this `StyleSheet` would be, so to say, "quenched" into the CDF file. That is, it will persist also if the CDF document will be open with another machine on which the changed `StyleSheet` is not installed. This is a bit longer, and I only recommend it, if you have a very long document with many cells to change, or if you need to change a whole number of style elements simultaneously. Let me know, if this is the case.

Comment: great; luckily I only had one cell to edit in this way.  It didn't occur to me to use this method (obviously!).  In fact I did this by simply editing the CDF document from within Mathematica (and, as per a recent comment of mine http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3172/4811 written to you, I avoided creating a CDF using the Export menu).